# Error al enviar parametros json por el metodo PUT en WebService cliente con java y jersey

Tags: php, java, webservice, curl, jersey

Tengo una aplicación WebService lado cliente en JAVA y lado servidor en PHP.

Estoy intentando enviar una solicitud con parametros json por CURL command como se ve a continuación:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X PUT  -d path=4920 -d message="I love you"  http://localhost:4321/idjserver/index.php/setCancion/
```

El WebService esta construido en SlimFrameWork de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->put('/setCancion/', function () use ($app) {
    $put=$app->request()->put();
    var_dump($put);  
});
$app->run();
```

De manera que la respuesta del comando CURL es:
[image: ver imagen]

Respuesta CURL:

```
array(2) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "4920"
  ["message"]=>
  string(7) "I love you"
}
```

El comando CURL se comporta como es esperado, pero por otro lado tengo cliente JAVA con Jersey donde  no puedo enviar los parametros json de forma correcta, estoy intentándolo con dos diferentes formas, este es mi código:

```
package idjplaymp4;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse;


public class ClienteServicioWeb {
    private static final String servicePath= "http://localhost:4321/idjserver/index.php";    
    private Client client = null;
    private WebTarget target = null;    
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public ClienteServicioWeb() {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        target = client.target(servicePath);
    }

    /**** Get Request *****/
    public Genero[] getMenu()
    {

        String menu = target.path("/getMenu").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);                    
        Genero[] g = gson.fromJson(menu, Genero[].class);   
        return g;
    }  

    /*** PRIMER FORMA *************/
    public void addSong(String songPath){
        JsonObject  inputJsonObj = new JsonObject();
        inputJsonObj.addProperty("path", songPath);
        inputJsonObj.addProperty("message", "Hello World");
        System.out.println(target.path("/setCancion/").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .put(Entity.entity(inputJsonObj,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), JsonObject.class));        
    } 

    /*** SEGUNDA FORMA *************/
    public void addSong(String songPath){
        String parametros="{\"path\":\""+songPath+"\"}";            
        String result = target.path("/setCancion/")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .put(Entity.entity(parametros, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);        
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);

    }         
}
```

la PRIMERA FORMA me retorna el siguiente error:

```
MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.google.gson.JsonObject, genericType=class com.google.gson.JsonObject.
```

La SEGUNDA FORMA me retorna un array vacio:

```
Result: array(0) {
}
```

Puede alguien echarme una mano!

Answer (score 1):

Yo veo detalles en ambos códigos en php y en java:
En php con slim framework yo hago algo como esto (fijate como paso parametros):

```
require ('Slim/Slim.php');
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app=new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/json/obtenerEmpleado/:id',function($id){
    $empleados=new ArrayObject();
    inicializar($empleados);
    $empleadoEncontrado=new Empleado();
    foreach ($empleados as $empleado){
        if ($empleado->id==$id){
            $empleadoEncontrado=$empleado;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($empleadoEncontrado);
});
$app->run();
```

Yo no hago cosas como esta `$put=$app->request()->put();` y no veo que aquí `$app->put('/setCancion/', function () use ($app)` se reciba un parámetro ya que `$app` esta fuera de la `function` y ademas en la url la variable no tiene nombre como en mi ejemplo: `:id`.

Ahora del lado de Java fijate como armo la url. Los parametros se separan con `/` y no llevan nombre, se acomodan por posición:

```
public void insertar(){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo Id: ");
        String id = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo nombre: ");
        String nombre = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo puesto: ");
        String puesto = br.readLine();
        String url="http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/restful/empleados/insertar/"+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(nombre,"UTF-8")+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(puesto,"UTF-8");
        //insertar es el nombre del método en php
        URL urlObj=new URL(url);
        //abrimos la conexion
        HttpURLConnection conexion=(HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conexion.connect();
        //Almacenamos la respuesta
        System.out.println(conexion.getResponseMessage());
        //System.out.println(resultado);
        conexion.disconnect();//desconecto la url
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

y ten cuidado con enviar los caracteres que dice en [la especificación de las URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) ya que están prohibidos.